# passing values from a db to jqplot

Tags: database, jqplot

Follwing is a part of my jsp page which plots the date and value as provided in

```
  var line1 = [['2013-07-02 18:34:22',27], ['2013-07-02 18:34:52',32]];
```

Using the date axis renderer and it is working as expected, Now here the values are hardcoded;

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1 = [['2013-07-02 18:34:22',27], ['2013-07-02 18:34:52',32]]; 
  var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart', [line1], {
      title:'VITALS CHART-TEMPERATURE', 
      axesDefaults: {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
          },
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          label:'TIME',
          tickOptions:{formatString:'%d/%m/%y\n%I:%M:%S %p'},
          tickInterval:'30 second'
        },

       yaxis:{
             label: 'TEMPERATURE'
           }

      },
      series:[{lineWidth:4,markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<center> 
<div id="chart" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I pass these values from a table in a database???. For example suppose I have a table with date|reading as two columns. I tried to format the data from the table in
the same format as

```
[['2013-07-02 18:34:22',27], ['2013-07-02 18:34:52',32]]
```

and pass it as the value of a hidden text field whose id is data and then changing the value of line1 as

```
   var line1 = document.getElementByID("data");
```

But Now I see that the plot disappears ...What will be the easiest way to get these values from a db and plot them...

Answer (score 0):

In rails I used [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) and defined it in my controller like this:

```
@testarray = []
Model.find_all.each do |ph|
  @testarray << [ph.created_at.to_formatted_s(:short), ph.value.to_f]
end
gon.array = @testarray
```

Testarray makes array what looks something like this:

```
[["10 Dec 14:10", 61.0],["10 Dec 13:38", 0.0],["11 Dec 10:08", 0.0],["11 Dec 10:06", 0.0],["10 Dec 14:12", 91369.0],["11 Dec 11:45", 31004.0]]
```

and now on my jsp I just replaced

```
var line1 = [['2013-07-02 18:34:22',27], ['2013-07-02 18:34:52',32]];
```

with

```
var line1=gon.array
```